# Convert string into dictionary<string, double>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I would like to convert a string like this:

```
value1: 0.3434,        
value2: 45.342,        
value3: 0
```

into a `Dictionary<string,double>`.

I tried couple of things:

```
var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, double>>(mystring);
```

This one doesn't work, the problem is that the string has several lines. ( \n ) therefore we get an exception right away.

```
 var dic = mystring.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(part => part.Split(':'))
               .ToDictionary(split => split[0], (split => double.Parse(split[1])));
```

I think this one almost works but we get "\r\n" at the beginning of each key.

Does someone have a cleaner solution?

Comment: the problem for the first is not the newlines, but the fact that your string _is not json_. and you could `Trim()` those newlines in your keys

Comment: Where is this string coming from?

Comment: From clipboard, or like outside txt file.

Comment: I'd do the second approach in your question, except call `Trim` on the split elements as Franz suggested, that would get rid of the new line characters.

Comment: Instead of `new[] { ',' }` use this: `new[] { ",", Environment.NewLine }`. This will treat the newlines as separators too and in conjuction with `RemoveEmptyEntries` you receive just the strings you want.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your strings coming from user source as you mentioned then processing it with a single line linq wouldn't be user friendly, because if any of the lines aren't parseable you get an exception without any information about wich line was bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't JSON and you just want simple string manipulation, start by cleaning the string (carriage returns and linefeeds are whitespace, along with tabs and quite a few others).  Give this a try:

```
  var cleanString = new string(mystring.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
  var s1 = cleanString.Split(',');
  var s2 = s1.Select(p => p.Split(':'));
  var d = s2.ToDictionary(split => split[0], (split => double.Parse(split[1])));
```

or your one-liner

```
  var dic = new string(mystring.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray())
    .Split(',')
    .Select(p => p.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(split => split[0], (split => double.Parse(split[1])));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not a valid **JSON** formatted string

you can write your string value-pair in a dictionary like the following

```cs
string mystring = @"value1: 0.3434,
value2: 45.342,
value3: 0";

Dictionary<string, double> dic = new Dictionary<string, double>();
string[] attributes = mystring.Split(",");
foreach (string s in attributes)
{
         string[] keyValuePair = s.Split(":");
         string key = keyValuePair[0];
         double value = Double.Parse(keyValuePair[1]);
         dic[key] = value;
}
```